# Property 'post' does not exist on type 'HttpClientModule'

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Currently I am learning MEAN stack tutorial, during auth service of the tutorial I have encounter some problem where Property 'post' does not exist on type 'HttpClientModule'. Where in the auth.service.ts file the post method is not recognize.

I have tried using import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http' but the modules does not exist maybe because the version of Angular I am using right?

```
//auth.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule , HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' 
})
export class AuthService {
  authToken: any;
  user: any;
  constructor(private http:HttpClientModule) { }
  registerUser(user){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user, {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}

//app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule , HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './components/profile/profile.component';
import { ValidateService } from './services/validate.service';
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path:'profile', component: ProfileComponent}
]
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpHeaders,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    FlashMessagesModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [ValidateService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

//angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "angular-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "angular:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "angular:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "angular"
}

//package.json
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "angular2-flash-messages": "^3.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with this part:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClientModule) { }
```

Should be:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' 
})
export class AuthService {
  authToken: any;
  user: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ...
```

`HttpClientModule` is a module to import in your app module, like this:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, BasicDialogComponent],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
```

Here is a good example [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#setup)

Comment: But I want to inject the http module into the constructor. Here is the link of the tutorial I am watching [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFftMN32jyQ) 1:48

Comment: In my app.module.ts do I need to import Headers aswell?

Comment: I have correct my code using your advice and now it cannot find name 'map'  for the code .map(res => res.json());

Comment: @ecksdee not in module...just in place you're using it (service) `import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: try `return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user, {headers: headers}) .pipe(map(res => res));` and import `map` operator like this `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` You, actually, don't need map in this case...just catch the error.

Comment: @ecksdee You don't want to inject the _module_ you want to inject the _class from the module_.

Comment: I have changed and apparently an error occured where Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object' from the line code res.json()

Comment: @ecksdee You also [don't need to `res.json()` any more](https://angular.io/guide/http), that tutorial is from 2017, which is **very old** in the Angular world.

Comment: Do you have any newer MEAN stack tutorial that I could learn? Yeah I noticed the video was published in 2017 which quite old.

Comment: @ecksdee Honestly, https://angular.io/ is a great resource and always up to date (the documentation site is generation from the source code of angular directly).